# Naive Bayes in Python

Tags: python, nlp, bayesian, naivebayes, smoothing

I'm trying to do Laplace smoothing on my Naive Bayes code. It gives me 72.5% accuracy on 70% train 30% test set, which is kinda low. Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
posTotal=len(pos)
negTotal=len(neg)

for w in larr:
  if (w not in pos) or (w not in neg):
    unk[w]+=1
    unkTotal=len(unk)
  else:
    if (w in pos):
      posP+=(math.log10(pos[w])-math.log10(posTotal))
    if (w in neg):
      negP+=(math.log10(neg[w])-math.log10(negTotal))
```

`pos` and `neg` are a defaultdic.

Comment: It would probably help to fix all of your indentations, it's not exceedingly readable

Answer (score 0):

My Python's a little rusty, but for the `if`, don't you want `if (w not in pos) and (w not in neg)`? Seems like this version would only adjust your scores for words that are somehow found in both `pos` and `neg`.